# HTML5 formatting on MacOS X? (preferably with TextMate)

Tags: html, text-editor, textmate, tidy, textmatebundles

Are there any editors or bundles available for MacOS X that support formatting of HTML5 documents? Tidy errors out on newer tags like canvas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657658/wanted-command-line-html5-beautifier) talks about how to make Tidy work with HTML5; tweaking the TextMate bundle's command line to use these params should work.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to add a HTML5 Tidy to TextMate by using the information found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2657658/wanted-command-line-html5-beautifier). Tidy does not seem to accept a custom string as a DocType, so I used a TextMate macro to insert a valid one. There probably is a more elegant way of doing this, but it gets the job done!

To start off, we need to create a TextMate command for Tidy that plays nice with HTML5. Access the "Bundle Editor" from the Bundles menu, and create a new command containing the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -wKU

require ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH'] + '/lib/ui.rb'
require ENV['TM_SUPPORT_PATH'] + '/lib/exit_codes.rb'

result = `"${TM_TIDY:-tidy}" -f /tmp/tm_tidy_errors -iq -utf8 \
          -wrap 0 --tab-size $TM_TAB_SIZE --indent-spaces $TM_TAB_SIZE \
          --indent yes \
          ${TM_XHTML:+-asxhtml --output-xhtml yes} \
          ${TM_SELECTED_TEXT:+--show-body-only yes} \
          --enclose-text yes \
          --doctype omit \
          --new-blocklevel-tags article,header,footer \
          --new-inline-tags video,audio,canvas,ruby,rt,rp \
          --break-before-br yes --vertical-space yes \
          --wrap-php no \
          --tidy-mark no`
status = $?.exitstatus

at_exit { File.unlink('/tmp/tm_tidy_errors') } # Clean up error log

if status == 2 # Errors

  msg = "Errors: " + File.read('/tmp/tm_tidy_errors')
  TextMate.exit_show_tool_tip msg

elsif status == 1 # Warnings - use output but also display notification with warnings

  log = File.read('/tmp/tm_tidy_errors').to_a.select do |line|
    ! (ENV['TM_SELECTED_TEXT'] and (line.include?('Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration') or line.include?("Warning: inserting missing 'title' element")))
  end.join rescue nil

  unless log.empty?
    options = {
      :title   => "Tidy Warnings",
      :summary => "Warnings for tidying your document (press escape to close):",
      :log     => log
    }
    TextMate::UI.simple_notification(options)
  end

end

if ENV['TM_SOFT_TABS'] == "YES"
  print result
else
  in_pre = false
  result.each_line do |line|
    unless in_pre
      tab_size = ENV["TM_TAB_SIZE"].to_i
      space, text = /( *)(.*)/m.match(line)[1..2]
      line = "\t" * (space.length / tab_size).floor + " "  * (space.length % tab_size) + text
    end

    print line

    in_pre = true  if line.include?("<pre>")
    in_pre = false if line.include?("</pre>")
  end
end
```

Name this command something along the lines of "HTML5 Tidy". Set the scope selection to "text.html". We'll set up a keyboard shortcut in a moment. Note that the "doctype" switch has been set to "omit", which removes the DocType declaration entirely.

You then need to record a macro from the Bundles menu with the following actions:

- Selecting the "HTML5 Tidy" command you just created
- Pressing CMD+Up to move to the beginning of the document
- Typing `<!DOCTYPE html>`
- Inserting a new line

Select the "Save Last Recording" menu item to store the macro. Name it something appropriate, such as "HTML5 Tidy + DocType", and set its scope to "text.html". You can then assign a keyboard shortcut for your completed macro using the "Key Equivalent" input.

This should allow you to use Tidy on your HTML5 documents without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do not about textmate bundles, but how about coda from panic? www.panic.com/coda

Answer (score 1):

John Muhl's html5 bundle - https://github.com/johnmuhl/html5.tmbundle

Answer (score 0):

Textmate has a bundle that will validate against the W3C validator - http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that I am not familiar with TextMate bundles because I do not personally use that editor. None the less, I found out that they have a [public subversion server](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/) where they keep different bundles. A quick search did not reveal any HTML5 bundle. You can find more information about bundles on their [website](http://wiki.macromates.com/Main/Bundles).

If you want an out of the box way of create web content in HTML5, have a look at [Aloha Editor](http://www.aloha-editor.org/).

Comment: The official subversion server holds only a subset of the available bundles in the TextMate universe.  These days GitHub is where new bundles pop up.  Using the GetBundles (note the "s") bundle finds several HTML5 bundles available.